# No view found for id to webview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I'm having the error "No view found for id" but I don't know exactly what I'm wrong and how to fix it.
I removed unnecessary or confidential pieces of code.

**MainActivity.class**
...

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager;

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   context = MainActivity.this;

   if(!checkTerm){

   if (isConnected(this)){

   fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

   fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_fragment, new FormTCLE(),"CONTRATO");

   fragmentTransaction.commit();

   }
   }
   }
```

**FormTCLE.class**

```
    public class FormTCLE extends Fragment {

    //atributos
    private WebView webView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_eva,null);

        webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("confidential");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //opening the form within the app, without redirection to the browser
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        return view;
    }
}
```

**form_eva.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".Forms.FormEva">

<WebView

android:id="@+id/webView"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLogin"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageLogin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pregnant"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/cpf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/txtCPF"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_cpf"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:theme="@style/ColorEditText"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/passwordLogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/txtPassword"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:theme="@style/ColorEditText"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!--Definindo e declarando os botões-->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttonLogin"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/model_button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_toRegister"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtToRegister"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_eva, container, false);` in `FormTCLE` fragment

Comment: I think you are missing something in activity_main.xml there is no layout with id `container_fragment` in `activity_main.xml`

Comment: @Zain isn't even coming to FormTCLE

Comment: @Udhaya is another layout but it is recognizing where this id is but it is in another xml

Comment: @AleffMatos You can't really do that. I mean you can only replace the layout with an id that belongs to the `MainActivity` context.

Comment: But in another class I use the same thing and `container fragment` doesn't have this id inside it

Comment: as a matter of time for delivery I did a webview on MainActivity and used it from there, but thanks to everyone who tried to help in some way (Udhaya and Zain)